# How to get the installed application name in a list

Tags: java, android

I have tried this:

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

this code gives me the list of the installed app's package name and etc. But I want only the application name's as a string type list. what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code ::: Refer this [LINK](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2010/07/getting-list-of-installed-application.html)

```
public class AppList extends Activity {
  ....
  private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
       results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
       Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
  } 
 }
}
```

in the above code "results" is the array list apps installed

Comment: results consists of all the app names installed

Comment: do accept the answer if it helped you out. click on the right check on the left side of the answer