# How to get all the installed application's name including system apps in a string array list in android

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I need to get all the application's **name** in an array list. Just apps name, nothing more. I have searched and I also know that there are so many solutions. But [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266022/how-to-get-the-installed-application-name-in-a-list) was my favourite. I coded it. But it show me error saying

> Required Object... Found ResolveInfo

for the code `for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)`

Please help me. I don't know what's wrong here...

Comment: Please post the stack trace and the relevant piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont write type, it will show type mismatch

Change below line

```
List list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

to

```
List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

Comment: `list.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());`

Comment: what is another issue? And if it is entirely different please accept current answer first.

Comment: About the code, Android Studio is saying **ResolveInfo** can't be applied to **String**

Comment: you have to do results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString()); not on list as per your sample